# Unable to load locally stored images faster into collection view.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a multiple images and video stored in application document directory. I am displaying that images and videos in collection view using SDWebImage in this way.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


AlbumImageCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AlbumImageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.albumImage.image=nil;
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[NSBundle  mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AlbumImageCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSInteger Type=[[[self.arrTbl_Album_Image objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:3] intValue];
if (Type==1) {
        cell.imgPlay.hidden=YES;
        [cell.albumImage setImage:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }else{
        cell.imgPlay.hidden=NO;
        [cell.albumImage setImage:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Here code for generating thumbnail.

```
-(void)load_Album_Data{
       NSUserDefaults *album_id=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
       NSInteger Album_id=[album_id integerForKey:@"album_Id"];

//From the query.
NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from tbl_Album_Image where album_id='%ld' order by id desc",Album_id];


//Get result.
if (self.arrTbl_Album_Image != nil) {
    self.arrTbl_Album_Image=nil;
}
self.arrTbl_Album_Image=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];


dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("MyQueue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{

for(int i=0;i<self.arrTbl_Album_Image.count;i++)
{
    NSInteger AssetType=[[[self.arrTbl_Album_Image objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:3] intValue];
    if (AssetType==1) {
       //for image 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *inputPath = [[self.arrTbl_Album_Image objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:2 ];

    NSString *imageEx=[inputPath pathExtension];
    NSString *imageName=[[inputPath lastPathComponent]stringByDeletingPathExtension];

    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",imageName,imageEx]];

    UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
    CGFloat scale = MAX(106/img.size.width, 106/img.size.height);
    CGFloat width = img.size.width * scale;
    CGFloat height = img.size.height * scale;
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake((106 - width)/2.0f,
                                  (106 - height)/2.0f,
                                  width,
                                  height);
    CGSize c=CGSizeMake(106, 106);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(c, NO, 0);
    [img drawInRect:imageRect];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    [images addObject:newImage];
    }
    else{
        //for video 
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *inputPath = [[self.arrTbl_Album_Image objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:2 ];

        NSString *imageEx=[inputPath pathExtension];
        NSString *imageName=[[inputPath lastPathComponent]stringByDeletingPathExtension];

        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",imageName,imageEx]];

        NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath];
        AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURL options:nil];

        AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
        imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
        NSError *err = NULL;
        CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 2);
        CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
        UIImage *thumbNailImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];


        CGFloat scale = MAX(106/thumbNailImage.size.width, 106/thumbNailImage.size.height);
        CGFloat width = thumbNailImage.size.width * scale;
        CGFloat height = thumbNailImage.size.height * scale;
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake((106 - width)/2.0f,
                                      (106 - height)/2.0f,
                                      width,
                                      height);
        CGSize c=CGSizeMake(106, 106);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(c, NO, 0);
        [thumbNailImage drawInRect:imageRect];
        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

             [images addObject:newImage];

    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             //Reload the Image view.
     [self.album_ImageView reloadData];
                   }


    });

}
});


 }
```

But the problem is i am unable to load images faster and also app is crash down when scroll up-down happen fast. And also for video image not generated.
Please help me to solve this problem and provide me any solution.
I want fast image loading in collection view cell.

Comment: give details of the crash, message and stack trace

Comment: @Wain see this detail 1)Received memory warning.2)Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x19c54caf0> { count = 1, contents =
 "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x19c54ce50> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}> 3)ImageIO: CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil ..This all comes when i scroll up-down collection view and application crash down

Comment: what are the images, how big are they, what format, which one is trying to be loaded when it crashes (presumably this also happens if you scroll down slowly and wait for each image to complete before going to the next cell)?

Comment: @Wain its all images selected from photos gallery no matter what size and type. It crash down because of slow to image load in collectionview and i scroll faster. can u suggest any other way to load images.?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ur code to set image change to this

```
 [cell.albumImage sd_setImageWithURL:imaURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]  options:SDWebImageRefreshCached   completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            cell.albumImage.image=image;
        });
    }];
```

It will load faster and even saves in cache

Comment: Received memory warning and also application crash down.

Comment: see this detail 1)Received memory warning.2)Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x19c54caf0> { count = 1, contents = "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x19c54ce50> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" } }> 3)ImageIO: CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil ..This all comes when i scroll up-down collection view and application crash down

Comment: Yes now i use another way by creating thumbnail of images but its still take some time to load in collection. i.e if album contain 500 photos then its still some time consume process.Suggest me if you have any other solution.

Comment: for the first time it will take time but from next time onwards it should not as it save the data in cache

Comment: Cache perform automatically.? or Can u suggest me how can i achieve this because it takes time for everytime when i enter in particular album view.which contain list of images.

Comment: r u using SDImageCache library

Comment: No by using SDWebImage application crash down because it takes time to load images and if i scroll up-down fast crash happens

Comment: you need to check why application crashes to just remove it is not a solution ...

Comment: Yes i did. it happen when image set to cell by SDWebImage when i scroll up-down faster and i dont know by using SDWebImage how to solve above listed error so i go for another way by creating thubnail.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like when you save the images from the photo library you should save the full size if you need it and save an appropriately scaled version of the image that you can use for display in the app. If using `ALAsset` that would likely be the `thumbnail`.

If you do that the image load will be quick and the memory usage minimal.

Currently you're simply trying to load too much image data into memory and that takes a long time and crashes the app when it inevitably runs out. Images taken with the device camera are actually very large...

Comment: Yes i apply this approach and create thumbnail for display in cell. And also working good for me but still there is load for sometime when image thumbnail is generating. See i am editing my code. tell me it is proper way or not. Because image load every time when i enter in particular album.

Comment: If you're saving the main images to disk I'd save the thumbnails too, in a directory beside the main images and with the same names so you don't need to do it all the time.